# How to transform these 2 python tuples and combine into a single one?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 tuples.

```
Tuple1 = (('James', 129L, 37L, 'IndexName1'), ('Jane', 231L, 23L, 'IndexName2')
Tuple2 = ((1L, 'IndexName1'), (2L, 'IndexName2'), (2L, 'IndexName3') )
```

I would like to transform these 2 tuples and convert into a single tuple that looks like this;

```
OutputTuple = (('James', 129L, 37L, 1L), ('Jane', 231L, 23L, 2L)
```

OutputTuple is almost the same as Tuple1. The difference is that the 4th element (IndexNameX) was replaced by a number that can be found in Tuple2.

How can this be done in Python? I am using Python 2.7

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. They work but I still have a problem. The actual Tuple1 looks like this;

```
Tuple1 = (('Jane', 231L, 23L, 'IndexName5'), ('James', 129L, 37L, 'IndexName1') )
```

There is an IndexName5 which does not have a corresponding match in Tuple2. When I run the code in the answers provided, an error appears. How do I ignore the cases where there are no corresponding match?

Comment: Quite an inconvenient design. Better use dictionary, definitely good idea for the second tuple.

Comment: @user3293156 What happens with IndexName1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a `dict` out of `Tuple2`:

```
Tuple2dict = {key: value for value, key in Tuple2}
```

Then make your `OutputTuple` using that lookup on the fourth element of each:

```
OutputTuple = tuple(x[:3] + (Tuple2dict.get(x[3], x[3]),) for x in Tuple1)
```

Comment: Would the following be better in terms of performance? 

`Tuple2dict = dict((y, x) for x, y in Tuple2)`

Comment: Yes that will do the same thing, but dict comprehension was added in 2.7, which your question said you're using. Might as well go with the newer preferred method

Comment: Your answer works but I still have a problem. 
I have Tuple1 like this Tuple1 = (('Jane', 231L, 23L, 'IndexName5'), ('James', 129L, 37L, 'IndexName1') )

There is an IndexName5 which does not have a corresponding match in Tuple2. When I run the code from your answer, an error appears. How do I ignore the cases where there are no corresponding match?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend another data structure, as sashkello suggests, but for now you can do:

```
for name, v1, v2, index_name in Tuple1:
    matching_index = None
    for val, label in Tuple2:
        if label == index_name:
            matching_index = val
    print(name, v1, v2, matching_index)
```

Output:

```
('James', 129L, 37L, 1L)
('Jane', 231L, 23L, 2L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with the other answers here, the fact is that dict is the data structure you should use in this situation. Here is what you need:

```
tupl = (('james', 129L, 37L, 'IndexName1'), ('jane', 231L, 23L, 'IndexName2'), ('y', 232L, 12L, 'IndexName5'))
for name, v1, v2, index_name in tupl:
    matching_index = 'none'
    for val, lable in tupl2:
        if lable == index_name:
            matching_index = val
            result.append((name, v1, v2, matching_index))
            result_tuple = tuple(result)

result_tuple(('james', 129L, 37L, 1L), ('jane', 231L, 23L, 2L), ('y', 232L, 12L, 'none'))
```